# How to define user efficiency time

Tags: efficiency, perceptron

I'm making a user study. Users had to perform the same task 10 times. I've recorded the completion times of each task. Now I need to calculate the **efficiency time**.

As you can imagine the user, when exposed to unfamiliar user interface always starts, with 0 efficiency. While participant uses the UI, efficiency increases and efficiency time decreases both logarithmically reaching its final value.

So I have the data for 10 tries of the same task and I need to get this efficiency time value for each user to sum up the experiments. I reckon there should be a statistical tool to calculate this, and this is what I'm looking for.

I wonder if any of you ever worked with something like this.

Please ask if you need clarification.

Comment: This depends on the definition you give to 'user efficiency'. There could be different definitions such as (1) the last-recorded time once familiarity with the UI kicks in (2) the rate of decrease of time to execute a task over the familiarization period (3) the number of tries/time elapsed until the user is capable of performing a task under a critical time constraint etc. Please define more clearly what you wish to calculate.

Comment: @ikonikon by **efficiency time** here I mean the minimum possible amount of time to complete the task. For example for a vacuum floating robot user the efficiency time is gonna be perfect let's say 6s. Real life users will always try to reach this perfect value gaining their own efficiency times. Do I make myself clear here? Please ask if you need further clarification.

Comment: @ikonikon I guess I'm hunting for this deviation from the "perfect efficiency time" (PET). I compare two stimuli. I assume comparing the average deviation from the PET will allow to conclude which stimuli performs better in terms of the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Presenting the minimum achieved time for each user is suggested in this case, since you are not interested in the degree of variability in response times, but rather in the best achievable performance (assuming that 10 trials is a large enough sample size for your task and the fact that recorded times are not subject to spurious phhenomena which may have introduced unaccounted variability in your analysis).

Comment: Thank for the answer. The problem is that the obtained times of completion wobble somewhere around the efficiency time value starting from Task4 or Task7 (depends on a user) and then trying to stabilise up to Task10. I guess this stabilising value is the efficiency time I'm looking for. I might be totally wrong though. What do you think?

Comment: Again, it is your choice to make, considering what you think is most useful. For example, you can choose to average the three smallest values for each user. Another idea is to identify the point where the steady-state behavior occurs for each user (this can be done in various ways such as looking for a shoulder-like point in a plot) and only average values thereafter.

Comment: woah! I think the second one is exactly my case! Could you please provide me with a link or something where I can read about this trick?

Comment: There is no single nor correct way of carrying out this procedure. One idea is to compute the mean across all values example is to compute the 9 difference values between your 10 times and define the shoulder point as the point where the maximum difference occurs. However, it may be the case that your plot has multiple such shoulders..what do you do then? In any case, I would strongly suggest visual inspection on a few graphs to ensure that the results are acceptable.